# Highcharts Add multiple hidden value to shared tooltive

Tags: highcharts

it's my first qestion in stack !
I try to add multiple hidden value in tooltip

my data example :

```
var sample1= [{y:3.1,ext1:'14.5',ext2:'14.5',color:'#0ef43c'},{y:2.9,ext1:'14.2',ext2:'14.5',color:'#30ff21'},{y:2.9,ext1:'14.2',ext2:'14.5',color:'#42ff2c'},etc...
var sample2= [{y:3.1,ext1:'14.5',ext2:'14.5',color:'#0ef43c'},{y:2.9,ext1:'14.2',ext2:'14.5',color:'#30ff21'},{y:2.9,ext1:'14.2',ext2:'14.5',color:'#42ff2c'},etc...
```

and my tooltip

```
 tooltip: {
            shared: true,
                 formatter: function() { 
                    var txt = Highcharts.dateFormat("<b>%Hh</b>", this.x);
                    txt += "<br /><b>Sample 1: </b>"+ this.points[0].point.y + " m - " + this.points[0].point.ext1 + "s" + this.points[0].point.ext2+ "s";
                    txt += "<br /><b>Sample 2: </b>"+ this.points[1].point.y + " m - " + this.points[1].point.ext1+ "s" + this.points[1].point.ext2+ "s";
                    txt += "<br />Sample 3: :" + this.points[2].point.y + " m";

                    return txt;

        }
        },
```

But there is problem with hidden data , so is there a way for use a code as
sample1.data.point.ext1
 instead of this.points[0].point.ext1 ?

Thanks

Comment: A live demo in http://jsfiddle.net would be nice

Comment: I think there should be `sample[index].ext1`. Where index is value of `this.x`.

Comment: Tkanks, i will try sample[index].ext1